# Confusing way readline() is operating

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling, readline

I am confused about how the `infile.readline()` function is operating in my code.

NOTE: Python interpreter v2.7.15(64-bit) is being used.

```
infile = open(r'C:\Users\pritish\Desktop\test_file_for_py.txt', 'r')
print infile.read(5)
print infile.read(5)
print infile.readline(2)
```

Where `test_file_for_py.txt` contains these lines:

```
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
This is line 4
This is line 5
This is line 6
This is line 7
This is line 8
```

In the above #TEST CODE 1 , `print infile.readline(2)`, gives output *ne*, which is as expected:

```
>>> infile = open(r'C:\Users\pritish\Desktop\test_file_for_py.txt', 'r')
>>> print infile.read(5)
This
>>> print infile.read(5)
is li
>>> print infile.readline(2)
ne
>>>
```

Now here's the catch, it keeps giving same result as below, no matter which value (greater than 4) I pass as an argument to `infile.readline()`.

```
>>> infile = open(r'C:\Users\pritish\Desktop\test_file_for_py.txt', 'r')
>>> print infile.read(5)
This
>>> print infile.read(5)
is li
>>> print infile.readline(5) # NOTE BELOW output
ne 1

>>>
>>> infile = open(r'C:\Users\pritish\Desktop\test_file_for_py.txt', 'r')
>>> print infile.read(5)
This
>>> print infile.read(5)
is li
>>> print infile.readline(8) #value is changed to 8 now , but still o/p same as previous(as like 5)
ne 1

>>>
```

Can anyone please explain, why `infile.readline()` is not returning characters from the next line even though I change `infile.readline()` argument to whatever value (>5)?

Comment: `readline` stops when it hits a `\n` character. `readline`, as the name suggests, is just supposed to read the current line.

Answer (score 3):

`readline` stops when it reaches a new-line character. The optional `size` argument specifies how many characters to read at most. If it encounters a newline before `size` characters are read, it stops anyway, and the `size` argument becomes irrelevant.

See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readline).